Вопрос по disnake
import disnake as discord  

import disnake  

from disnake.ext import commands  

bot = commands.Bot(activity=disnake.Game(name="игру"))  

 

activity = disnake.Activity(  

    name="за сообщениями",  

    type=disnake.ActivityType.watching,  

)  

bot = commands.Bot(activity=activity)  

@bot.event  

async def on_ready():  

    print("Бот готов!")  

@bot.event  

async def on_message(message):  

    if message.author != bot:  

        # Выведите имя отправителя сообщения  

        print(f"Сообщение от {message.author}: {message.content}")   
 

bot.run("Токен")

когда я отсылаю сообщение показывается

"Сообщение от stepaandgd: "

, что делать

Вы точно включили необходимые интенты для просмотра сообщений?
Укажите интент просмотра сообщений при запуске бота
intents = disnake.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(activity=disnake.Game(name="игру"), intents=intents)

Затем перейдите в портал разработчиков. Выберите своего бота, перейдите в раздел "Bot" и под "Privileged Gateway Intents" включите необходимые интенты.

